# Uploading screen winforms c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, upload, picturebox

We are making a program that downloads and uploads an xml(maximum 500kb) file from a ftp server. we need to make an uploading screen. We tried three methods. In the first method we used a .gif file which shows a loading screen which we've put in a picture box. After that, before we process the up-/download function, we make the picture box visible and when the function finishes, we make it invisble. But it didn't work :( here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//upload button
{

    picturebox1.visible=true;  //.gif file
    upload();
    picturebox1.visible=false;
}
```

Here is the upload function:

```
void upload()
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + IP + ":" +                  Port + downdest + xmlfile);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    //Load the file
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("apartman.xml");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream.Close();

    //Upload file
    Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    reqStream.Close();
}
```

Using this code, uploading works but we dont see the picture. When the upload code is not working we don't see the loading screen either.

Then we tried multithreading, but c# doesn't allow us to use this code in a seperate thread.

```
picturebox1.visible=true;
```

It says something like: "you cannot also call this bla bla...". I don't remember and also erased the code so sorry for the missing information.

Lastly we tred to use a backgroundworker, here is the code:

```
public Form1()
{
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//upload button
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}


private void upload()
{
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //upload
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("upload complete");
}
```

This code also gives an error message that states:

> Error 1   Files has invalid value ""updates":". Illegal characters in path.xml2

Does anyone know the correct method of programming a loading screen?
If you need more details I can surely answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your first snippet is that there isn't enough time for the UI thread to change the status of your loading image: When you show up your image by changing its visibility, you immediately start the uploading process, which blocks the UI thread and prevent it from taking your changes into effect, that is, to show your loading image.

After the upload finishes, you immediately hide your image. At that moment, the UI thread tries to show your image (the pending change to take into effect) and immediately hide your image after that, which explains why you never see it.

To correct this behavior, you need to move the upload process in another thread. Which you tried to do but were not successful to get it to work.

There are many ways to do this depending on your .NET version. The background worker is a good one and probably your best bet. Just make sure, whenever you want to update the UI from within a thread context, that you are using a dispatcher to update it:

```
Dispatcher dispUI = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
dispUI.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            //From here you can safely 
            //hide your loading image
        }), null
            );
```